# LabView Mindstorms - What does speed in seconds mean?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, labview

I'm trying to set a motor to spin exactly at 60rpm, and I'm using LabView for Lego Mindstorms.

However, when reading the documentation for the move motor block, it says this:

> Power/Speed specifies the amount of power, from -100 to 100, with
>   which you want to move the motors or the speed, in seconds, at which
>   you want to move the motors. Use the polymorphic selector below the VI
>   icon to specify whether you want to set the power or the speed at
>   which the motors move.

Here's a screenshot of the docs:
http://puu.sh/l4FzP/c4d0b8faa7.png

So, what does the "the speed, in seconds, at which you want to move the motors." mean? I've tried setting it at one, and the motor **barely** moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A speed in second makes no sense to me.

Are there more information about this motor, like to maximum rpm/power ? If so, maybe that the scale from -100 to 100 is some sort of percentage of max rpm/power, with the positives being one rotation direction and the negatives the other ?

Comment: I did some research (http://www.philohome.com/nxtmotor/nxtmotor.htm), and at the same time I was tinkering with the speed in seconds setting via a PID. The speed in seconds reached 60rpm at a value between 37 and 38.

The websited I mentioned before says the full-battery motor with no load is capable of ~160rpm, and the 37.5% of 160rpm is 60rpm, While this may be a coincidence and needs further testing, it could be a valid hypothesis to state that **the speed in seconds represents a percentage of the max rpm**